# Regular Expression to check if a String contains '1-n' Integers and then '0-m' Alphabets

Tags: java, regex, string

I got a peculiar situation where I need to validate a String.

String has to satisfy some criteria to move further. which are :

1. String should start with an Integer value whose length should be > 1
   and < n
2. and then followed by alphabets whose length should be from 0 to m (which means alphabet may be present or may not be present)

`myString.charAt(0)` is giving me if the string starts with Integer.

How to validate it contains only < n integers ?

How to validate it is by > 0 and < n integers followed by 0 to < m alphabets ?

can I get a regular expression to solve it ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'alphabets' ? Just letters?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes can you explain in detail ?

Comment: @DarthAndroid yes I meant letters

Comment: This maybe `\d{1,n}[a-z]{0,m}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
^\d{1,n - 1}[A-Za-z]{0,m - 1}$
```

As you want `< n`. So it should be `n-1`

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/wQ1rF5/1)

Code in JAVA

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexMatches
{
    static boolean isValid(String x, int n, int m)
    {
       String pattern = "^\\d{1," + (n - 1) + "}[A-Za-z]{0," + (m - 1) + "}$";

       Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

       Matcher t = r.matcher(x);
       return t.find();
  }
public static void main( String args[] ){

  // String to be scanned to find the pattern.
  String line = "123abcdef";
  int n = 4, m = 4;

  if (isValid(line, n, m)) {
        System.out.println("FOUND");
  } else {
        System.out.println("NOT FOUND");
  }

  }
}
```

The value of `n` should be greater than or equal to `2` and the value of `m` should be greater than `1`

**[IDEONE DEMO](http://ideone.com/E4Dnu6)**

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes Logically your second comment should be correct. I am not sure about syntax though

Comment: I forked your sample, it would be [`return x.split(pattern).length == 0;`](http://ideone.com/eejXYp)

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes Yes its working. Thanks for out of box answer

Comment: Last thing ;) ... You should say the restrictions: `n>2` and `m>1` (due to regex range `{x,y}` where y must be greater than x)

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes That I was expecting from OP..Anyways I have edited it

Answer (score 1):

You can match this with a very simple regex:

```
^(\d+)([A-z]*)$
```

1 or more digits, followed by 0 or more letters. You can very easily grab the capture groups to find out exactly how many digits or how many letters are in the string. If you know `m` and `n` ahead of time as specific numbers, then insert them into the regex like so:

For n = 4 and m = 3,

```
^(\d{1,4})([A-z]{0,3})$
```

This will match `0000aaa`, but not `aaa` or `000aaaa`.

Comment: can you please give a function where I can send `isValid(string, n, m)` and get result ?

Answer (score 0):

Another variant of the solution that we have seen so far. All answers are really good. This should also match unicode.

**Pattern**

```
\b\p{N}{1,n}\p{L}{0,m}\W
```

**Source Code**

```
    public static void matchNumeroAlphaString(){
        int n = 3; 
        int m = 3;
        String text    =
            "John32 54writes about this, 444 and 456Joh writes about that," +
                    " and John writes #about 9EveryThing. ";

       String patternString = "\\b\\p{N}{1," + n + "}\\p{L}{0," + m + "}\\W";


        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

        while(matcher.find()) {
           System.out.println("Found: " + matcher.group());
        }
    }
```

**Output**

Found: 444
Found: 456Joh